# Расайз окна при помощи jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть самый обычный скрипт для ресайза:

```
function heightDetect() {
    $(".carousel").css("height", $(window).height());
}
heightDetect();

$(window).resize(function(){
    heightDetect();
});
```

Скрипт проверенный, не первый раз использую. Но вот возникла проблема с которой столкнулся впервые. Хочу сделать "карусель" во весь экран,при первой загрузки страницы ничего не происходит, скрипт срабатывает только если ИЗМЕНИТЬ ХОТЬ НА ОДИН ПИКСЕЛЬ разрешение экрана! После обновления страницы все возвращается обратно.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой? Подскажите пожалуйста как решить ее?

Comment: Может при выполнении скрипта объекта $(".carousel") еще нет? В каком месте вы загружаете скрипт? Попробуйте добавить в функцию строку console.log($(".carousel")), чтобы посмотреть, находит он такой элемент или нет

Comment: @Сергей Странно, оно начинает видеть его только после изменения размера экрана. Скрипт я загружаю сразу после$(document).ready(function(){ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот корректный вариант. Работает отлично:

```
function heightDetect() {
    $(".carousel").css("height", $(window).height())
}
$(window).on("load",function(){
    heightDetect();
});
```

Нужно просто поменять resire на onload.

Comment: Не поменять. Теперь на resize работать не будет.

Answer (score 0):

Можно на всякий еще добавить событие resize, в дополнение к load если окно может менять свои размеры, то обязательно

Comment: да, как вариант...)